# How to make a turnover efffect by swiper.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile, swiper.js

Below is the mockup, I don't know how to make it. 
Expected: tap on left big img on vertical, then the right can add `.active` to the correct item. But left effect is hard to implement.
Could someone help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bppiA.jpg)